# How to use a USB 485 in the Pi

Tags: debian, usb

I have a Hjelmslund USB485 that I want to work with my Pi. How do I do?

From dmesg I can read:

```
[ 4170.320524] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[ 4170.431092] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c40, idProduct=0479
[ 4170.431122] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4170.431139] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB485 Iso gland
[ 4170.431167] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Hjelmslund Electronics
[ 4170.431183] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: HEVW15XG
```

From the lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1c40:0479 EZPrototypes
```

How can I connect it as a /dev/ttyUSB0 or alike?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to change the VID and PID with FTDI software FT Prog (utility for programming the EEPROM of FTxxx devices). Change to 0403 and 6001, Linux will then recognise it as a generic FTDI.

Comment: Do you think that after you do that, you can use the FTDI royalty free drivers? I'd be interested to see if you got this to work.

Comment: Yes it worked! Rasbian recognised the drivers and I tested sending command through cutecom to a controller device.

Comment: glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

As this is not a storage device, you cant really `mount` it. I mean you could connect to it, but the information would be meaningless.

I did however find the following [FAQ on Hjelmslund website](http://www.hjelmslund.dk/Faq.asp).

> Question : Err - what about Linux?
>   Answer : There are Linux drivers available, but some tweeking is necesarry to use them so we don't support it yet - but a solution is coming soon. Feel free to mail for further informations.

The only thing you can do for now is email them, I'm sure they have at least a beta driver.

Comment: Thanks for the input. No, acctually they don't, read my post below :)